# Wordpress doesn't create thumbnails for image

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating my wordpress theme from zero, using template from underscores.me.
But now I have a problem, Wordpress doesn't create thumbnails for image.
I tried to add my own image sizes, by adding this code to functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-small', 320, 9999, false );
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium', 425, 9999, false );
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium_large', 768, 9999, false );
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-large', 1024, 9999, false );
```

So I tried made it using hook

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'true_add_image_size' );

function true_add_image_size() {
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-small', 320, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium', 425, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium_large', 768, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-large', 1024, 9999, false );
}
```

But anything doesn't work, I upload new images, open uploads folder, and there is only one image copy, there are not thumbnails. Image sizes is added (I can see it), but WP doesn't change images

thumbnails support is turn on

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I use a local host xampp

Answer (score 1):

Go to wp `dashboard > site health` and try fixing the recommendations.

As for the image, it is highly likely the `gd` extension is disabled.

1. open `php.ini` from xampp.
2. uncomment `extension=gd`. ( ctrl + f and type `extension=gd`)
3. restart the server.

***Note*** that you may note see the multiple sizes being generated for previously set images but the newer ones. I just came across the same issue and fixed it like this.